# R - using ggplot for line chart - no line showing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot and geom_line but there is no line showing up.

I used this command:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(campaigns, aes(x=Send.Time, y=Open.Rate, color='red')) + geom_line()
```

Please see screenshot below

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: You're trying to plot a categorical variable. Type `data[,2]` into your R console and hit enter - you will see it is text as the numbers have a `%` at the end - like `"12%"`. R will not treat this like a number, but rather like a string like `"apple"`. You will need to convert your data to numeric first.

Comment: @thelatemail I updated my question using GG plot but no line is showing

Comment: @thelatemail has answered your question. It's an issue of the variable types, not the particular graphing library.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "%" from the string and convert into numeric. Please see the code below:

```
# Simulation
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

campaigns <- data.frame(
Send.Time = c("5/30/17", "6/1/17", "6/1/17", "6/6/17", "6/8/17", "6/15/17"),
Open.Rate = c("33.40%", "9.14%", "29.64%", "24.90%", "8.07%", "32.44%")
)


# convert to numeric
campaigns <- campaigns %>% mutate(Open.Rate = as.numeric(gsub("%", "", as.character(Open.Rate))))

# plot 
campaigns %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Send.Time), y = Open.Rate), colour = "red") +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = campaigns$Send.Time, breaks = seq_along(campaigns$Send.Time)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Session date")
```

Output:
[image: Plot]